# MTurk external website example

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, mechanicalturk

I am looking for a example where a fully completed web app can be embedded into amazon mechanical turk. I am working on a "game-like" activity that does not really belong to a form structure.

Here is my game/activity:
http://52.91.100.69:3030/

I would like to embed such tasks inside mechanical turk. My code accepts url parameters such as assignmentId, workerId etc (which I have found form the aws mturk docks)
For example:
http://52.91.100.69:3030/?assignmentId=23423&workerId=34&hitId=455

Basically, I am handling all the data logging etc, I plan to generate codes for users to enter upon completion of a number of tasks.

I would like to know how I cam accomplish this? Preferably in python (Boto)?

I looked at this tutorial: http://kaflurbaleen.blogspot.com/2014/06/in-which-i-battle-mturk-external-hits.html

Using this I made this boto file: https://gist.github.com/arendu/631a416e4cb17decb9dd

When I run it I dont see any errors, but I can't seem to find out whether the hit is available? I checked my aws mturk requester console (looked at manage HITs individually) but no hits are present.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know boto, so I'm not sure if there are details set by default. If not, your `create_hit_result` operation is missing a number of parameters required by the API (expiration, duration, all the parameters you commented out, etc.). That said, if you're giving a code, you don't want an ExternalQuestion HIT, you just want a QuestionForm or HTMLQuestion HIT that includes a link to your activity. ExternalQuestion should only be used if your HIT application ends by posting back the AssignmentId and at least one other field to the MTurk External Submit URL.

Comment: Also, [Response Groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_CommonParametersArticle.html#response-groups) just control what information is displayed in the API response. They're pretty meaningless in most situations.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, I am not fixed on boto, even doing it through command line tools would work for me. Are there examples of HTMLQuestion for my use case or something similar?

Comment: This is somewhat self-promotional, but I have [a tutorial that might be relevant](https://github.com/leeper/MTurkR/wiki/Surveys), though it it is written using MTurkR (my package for R) rather than boto.